# Loading KEXT without rebooting on Big Sur

Tags: macos, kernel, macos-big-sur, kernel-extension

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/installing-a-custom-kernel-extension) it is necessary to reboot macOS when loading (or updating the KEXT). I have already disabled SIP. However, it is still cumbersome to do a reboot, especially for development. I know that KEXTs are deprecated and that the KEXT cache has to be rebuilt. However, is there some (undocumented) possibility to load/update the KEXT without having to reboot?

I did some research and tried some `boot-args` options without success.

Answer (score 3):

No, from Big Sur onwards, all loadable kexts are linked into a single pre-linked kernel image, and it's not possible to mark kernel pages as executable after a certain stage has been reached during boot.

Attempting to load a kext which is not in that image adds it to the list to be included in the prelinked image. The reboot then causes the new pre-linked kernel to be loaded.

Yes, it's annoying, but no, there's no workaround, other than using 10.15/Catalina for debugging/testing when you're not specifically dealing with 11.0/Big Sur issues.

Comment: Is it possible to load a kext directly into the boot volume, rather than having the OS do it?  I have an installer which is not loading the kext properly (infinitely requiring reboot but never actually loading the kext it seems)

Comment: @Demis I think, if I understand you correctly, the direct answer to your question is essentially no, but that doesn’t mean there’s no solution to the underlying problem you’re running into. I recommend you ask a new question, and give all details you can provide about your kext as well as a more detailed explanation of the problem you are running into. If you tag it with iokit and kernel-extension tags, I’ll definitely see it.

Comment: Thanks, I did figure out a less convoluted way to get my broken software (google drive (prev. file stream)) to work - turned out that Disabling other KExt's solved it, indicating that old/conflicting KExt's are the problem (not entirely unike like Mac OS 7/8/9's 'Extensions'!).  Things like old print drivers etc.